# In the multiple module configuration, how are the module methods get called?

Tags: php, phalcon

in **public/index.php**:

```
public function main()
{

    $this->_registerServices();

    //Register the installed modules
    $this->registerModules(array(
        'frontend' => array(
            'className' => 'Multiple\Frontend\Module',
            'path' => '../apps/frontend/Module.php'
        ),
        'backend' => array(
            'className' => 'Multiple\Backend\Module',
            'path' => '../apps/backend/Module.php'
        )
    ));

    echo $this->handle()->getContent();
}
```

---

in **module.php**:

```
class Module
{
    public function registerAutoloaders()
    {

        $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
            'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers' => '../apps/frontend/controllers/',
            'Multiple\Frontend\Models' => '../apps/frontend/models/',
        ));

        $loader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Register the services here to make them general or register in the ModuleDefinition to make them module-specific
     */
    public function registerServices($di)
    {

        //Registering a dispatcher
        $di->set('dispatcher', function () {
            $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();

            //Attach a event listener to the dispatcher
            $eventManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
            $eventManager->attach('dispatch', new \Acl('frontend'));

            $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventManager);
            $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\\");
            return $dispatcher;
        });


        //Registering the view component
        $di->set('view', function () {
            $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
            $view->setViewsDir('../apps/frontend/views/');
            $view->registerEngines(array(".phtml" => 'volt'));
            return $view;
        });
    }
}
```

I want to know how the methods `registerServices` && `registerAutoloaders` in the module are called.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the MVC repo in github:

https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple

The idea is that your application has one entry point `public\index.php`. In that file you have:

```
public function main()
{
    $this->_registerServices();

    //Register the installed modules
    $this->registerModules(
        array(
            'frontend' => array(
                'className' => 'Multiple\Frontend\Module',
                'path' => '../apps/frontend/Module.php'
            ),
            'backend' => array(
                'className' => 'Multiple\Backend\Module',
                'path' => '../apps/backend/Module.php'
            )
        )
    );

    echo $this->handle()->getContent();
}
```

See the full file [here](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/blob/master/multiple/public/index.php).

Now in the `public\index.php` file you have instructed Phalcon that you have two modules, one the frontend and one as the backend and the location/class of the respective `Module.php` files.

Inside one of these `Module.php` files (say frontend) you will find:

```
namespace Multiple\Frontend;

class Module
{

    public function registerAutoloaders()
    {

        $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces(
            array(
                'Multiple\Frontend\Controllers' => '../apps/frontend/controllers/',
                'Multiple\Frontend\Models'      => '../apps/frontend/models/',
            )
        );

        $loader->register();
    }

    public function registerServices($di)
    {

        //Registering a dispatcher
        $di->set(
            'dispatcher', 
            function () 
            {
                $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();

                //Attach a event listener to the dispatcher
                $eventManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
                $eventManager->attach('dispatch', new \Acl('frontend'));

                $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventManager);
                $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("Multiple\Frontend\Controllers\\");
                return $dispatcher;
            }
        );

        //Registering the view component
        $di->set(
            'view', 
            function () 
            {
                $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
                $view->setViewsDir('../apps/frontend/views/');
                return $view;
            }
        );

        $di->set(
            'db', 
            function () 
            {
                return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(
                    array(
                        "host"     => "localhost",
                        "username" => "root",
                        "password" => "secret",
                        "dbname"   => "invo"
                    )
                );
            }
        );

    }

}
```

These functions are called automatically once the module is registered (with `registerModules` in the `public\index.php`. In this module, the `registerAutoloaders` and `registerServices` further customize the module giving you better control of what is going on. For instance you might have a different autoloader in one module than another, or have one module accessing a different database than another. You can set all those in the specific `Module.php`.

I know there is talk about making a brand new set of tutorials with single/multiple configurations, but it hasn't materialized yet.

Comment: i mean, in public/index.php use registerModules register the module,and the module's method registerAutoloaders and registerServices is automatically call? who call this two method? in framework c language definition？

Comment: Phalcon calls it automatically. If you have the `registerAutoloaders` and `registerServices` in the `Module.php` file, they will be called, so long as the module is registered in the `public\index.php`

Comment: oh, i understand, but if These methods （automatically work method） not write in doc, i only try it
besides，controller's initialize() method is automatically call ?

Comment: @netstu I will correct the documentation to mention that. Thanks!